# Facebook SDk Errors

Tags: android, android-facebook

I down latest facebook sdk  from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/android/) and it gives me a zip i extract it. Now i dont find any jar file but number of samples and facebook.apk and html and css files . Now i import these project i found bunch of errors in each samples code. For this i clean all and fix properties of all project now there is liberaryy project which is facebookSDK now i add this in all samples. And ron my first sample BooleanOSGame, HelloFacebook, SampleLoginProject but all these projects are not running and giving error on console. any help would be appreriated

```
1-FacebookSDk.apk not found.
2-class not found "com.facebook.LoginActivity"
3- etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to Import the JAR to Eclipse.
Please have a look at Step 3 [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) - [HowToAddJar](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)

Comment: i import all samples with FacebookSDK but which jar file i have to import beacause there is no jar file in the facebookSDKversion 3.0.2 folder

Comment: i know how to add jar but problem is which jar i have to add for facebook??

Comment: this [tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1) helped me

Comment: ok its help me with those samples which required hash keys. but samples like ProfilePicturePicker does not requird it but on running it is giving classnotfound exception